# VSCODE - Explorer extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a question:
Can i hide the filename extensions from the vscode explorer?

I want it to display some files as: **UserDetailService** insted of **UserDetailService.java**

I look the configurations and couldn't find some option for it.

[image]

Comment: "Hiding extensions" is one of the *WORST* ideas Microsoft ever had!!!  Why would anybody want to DELIBERATELY do this???

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do this.  Here is a recent issue that was closed for not much interest: [Add File Explorer Setting to hide files .extensions ( not always necessary with icons)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152035)